# How I can create a command that can be treated as a number?

Tags: width

I need to put a symbol over some text, I want to use `\hspace{#1}` where `#1` is the width of the `#1` text used.

For example, write `\mycommand{p}{b}` and the result to be shown like the `b` over the `p`, just like the symbol `\th`, but allowing me to write more than one letter.

For example, `\mycommand{text1}{\LaTeX}`, placing the word `\LaTex` over the word `text`

Comment: Perhaps it's better if you tell exactly what you have in mind: I think that `\hspace` is not what you need. Probably there are better ways.

Comment: Perhaps `\settowidth{\mylen}{Some text}` is what you want ([see here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Length_manipulation)).  The command as given sets `\mylen` to the width of the 'Some text'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution based on the `stackengine` package. I define a `\superimpose` command with two mandatory arguments and one optional (the alignment: `r`, `l` or `c` — the default):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor} 
    \usepackage{etoolbox} 
    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \newcommand\superimpose[3][]{%
    \def\stackalignment{#1}
    \stackon[0pt]{\smash{#2}}{#3}\vphantom{#2}\def\stackalignment{c}}

    \begin{document}

    \superimpose{\LaTeX}{\color{red}text}

    \superimpose[l]{\LaTeX}{\color{green}text}

    \superimpose[r]{\LaTeX}{\color{blue}text}

    \end{document}
```

[image: compiled example]

Answer (score 8):

If you want to measure the width of a text, you can do by using a length with

```
\newlength{\mylen}
```

in the preamble and then

```
\settowidth{\mylen}{text to measure}
```

when you need it; you can use `\mylen` in the argument of `\hspace`, for instance.

I'm not sure what this is for, but here's how you can do it without any measuring.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\overwrite}[2]{%
  {\ooalign{\hfil#1\hfil\cr\hfil#2\hfil\cr}}\vphantom{#1#2}}

\begin{document}
\overwrite{p}{b}

\overwrite{text}{\LaTeX}
\end{document}
```

No need to measure things, as TeX knows how to do it.

[image]

Comment: It worked!
Anyway, I would like to know how to set a the word length as a variable.

Comment: @hkviktor I added it.